How to get list of channels and members in microsoft teams bot
I am building a Microsoft Teams bot, and I noticed we have a method available in botbuilder: TeamsInfo.getTeamChannels(turnContext, teamId).
Can you please help me understand how it works? How is the turnContext returning data for a team? From my Teams app developer portal, I assigned all the necessary scopes. Don’t I need to use some Graph APIs, or will this method work as is?
Also, in response to the above call, I received this output, in which one channel name is missing, though the channel name is general:
what is right way to fetch list of members and channel in a team where my bot is added..People are interacting with this bot in their personal DM
[
  {
    "name": undefined,
    "id": "19:nGtWIyKBcs0m93LgdScfymNX4_YhoaEj0Zo1@thread.tacv2"
  },
  {
    "name": "newchannel",
    "id": "19:42baf94a1a3e86cb0@thread.tacv2"
  },
  {
    "name": "testchannel",
    "id": "19:54b4ac2af6228c4573fff12@thread.tacv2"
  }
]


The same issue is being tracked here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/how-to-get-list-of-channels-and-members-in-teams-bot/m-p/4261777#M10901. Please follow the above-mentioned thread for further updates.
